# How can I read CSV files using Spark in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, etl

I am new to spark and I want to read csv files from my computer using spark in a springboot App.

I tried follwoing a guide and I tried running this code but I encounter an error :

```java
Dataset<Row> csvDatas = spark
    .read()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load(filePath);
csvDatas.show();
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.lang.String java.net.URI.scheme accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7d3a22a9
```